# Effectiveness of request with pagination

Tags: android, performance, rest, pagination

I had heard, that `Android` application should strive to avoid unnecessary network requests for saving of battery, e.t.c.
I need to make a `request` which supports `pagination`.
There around 10k items in `response`.
So, I want to set `itemsPerPage` parameter to 10k and fetch all data at once to prevent extra overhead with making of a lot of small requests where `itemsPerPage` is small.
Pagination is good when you do not need all data at once, but I need.
This is the case when I do not have UI, I need to save items in DB, so I need all of them. I mean pagination on the level of Rest-API, not UI.

So, what will be more efficient? a lot of small requests or one huge?
Thanks. Does huge response (800kb) have some pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

Read this below link, understand and implement

http://androidkt.com/rest-api-pagination-paging-library/

Comment: Does this article answer the main question of this topic? I mean, "what will be more efficient? a lot of small requests or one huge?". As I can see, this article shows how to implement such kind of request, but I know how to do this. I just strive to find how to make it in the more performant way. In any case, thanks for your post.

Comment: first two para tells about that and remaining is the implementation, why to call one huge request, it will be 1. time consuming, 2. memory consuming, 3. Data consumption even if not required. Once have a look at ur gmail app (an example),  why to load all the 1k+ mails at once even if only 10 to 20 items are visible to the user

Comment: As I wrote in my description ("Pagination is good when you do not need all data at once, but I need. ") this is the case when I do not have UI, I need to save items in DB, so I need all of them. I meant pagination on the level of Rest-API, not UI. Thanks.

Comment: I had extended my question for clarity.